# Flutter replace widget with SlideTransition

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to slide out my first widget from right and slide in second from left of screen.

I'm trying to use `AnimatedSwitcher` with `SlideTransition`

my current code bug is that first widget doesn't slide out and just vanishes

here is my complete code snippet.
Any help would be appriciated

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static const int PIN_CODE_LENGTH = 4;
  final TextEditingController _mobileController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _pinController = TextEditingController();
  final UniqueKey _mobileKey = UniqueKey();
  final UniqueKey _pinKey = UniqueKey();

  bool _submittable = false;
  bool _isLoginStepOne = true;
  String _buttonText = Strings.next;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: SizePercentConfig.screenHeight,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _buildHeader(),
                Expanded(
                  child: _buildForm(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHeader() {
    return Container(
      height: SizePercentConfig.safeBlockVertical * 60,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: SizePercentConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 30,
            left: SizePercentConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 30,
            child: Image.asset(
              Assets.logo,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: SizePercentConfig.safeBlockVertical * 50,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    Assets.loginHeader,
                    width: SizePercentConfig.screenWidth,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildForm() {
    return Form(
      onChanged: _validate,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimens.unitX2),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
                  final inAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
                          begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
                      .animate(animation);
                  final outAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
                          begin: Offset(-1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
                      .animate(animation);

                  print('** child key: ${child.key}');
                  print('** mobile key: $_mobileKey');
                  print('** pin key: $_pinKey');
                  if (child.key == _mobileKey) {
                    // in animation
                    print('>>>>>>> first statement');
                    return ClipRect(
                      child: SlideTransition(
                        position: inAnimation,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: child,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    // out animation
                    print('>>>>>>> second statement');
                    return ClipRect(
                      child: SlideTransition(
                        position: outAnimation,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: child,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                layoutBuilder:
                    (Widget? currentChild, List<Widget> previousChildren) {
                  return currentChild!;
                },
                child: _isLoginStepOne
                    ? AppTextField(
                        key: _mobileKey,
                        controller: _mobileController,
                        hint: Strings.mobileNumber,
                        textInputType: TextInputType.phone,
                      )
                    : _buildPinCode()),
            SizedBox(height: Dimens.unitX2),
            AppSolidButton(
              onPressed: _buttonAction,
              text: _buttonText,
              width: SizePercentConfig.screenWidth,
              enabled: _submittable,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: Dimens.unitX2),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _validate() {
    if (_isLoginStepOne) {
      if (Regex.mobileRegex.hasMatch(_mobileController.value.text) !=
          _submittable)
        setState(() {
          print('--> setState called in _validate');
          _submittable = !_submittable;
        });
    } else {
      if ((_pinController.value.text.length == 4) != _submittable)
        setState(() {
          print('--> setState called in _validate');
          _submittable = !_submittable;
        });
    }
  }

  void _buttonAction() {
    if (_submittable) {
      setState(() {
        print('--> setState called in _buttonPressed');
        _isLoginStepOne = false;
        _submittable = false;
        _buttonText = Strings.login;
      });
    } else {}
  }

  Widget _buildPinCode() {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: PinCodeTextField(
        key: _pinKey,
        controller: _pinController,
        appContext: context,
        length: PIN_CODE_LENGTH,
        onChanged: (_) {},
        enablePinAutofill: true,
        enableActiveFill: true,
        textStyle: TextStyle(color: Palette.scorpion),
        pinTheme: PinTheme(
          shape: PinCodeFieldShape.circle,
          fieldHeight: SizePercentConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 20,
          fieldWidth: SizePercentConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 20,
          activeFillColor: Palette.concrete,
          inactiveFillColor: Palette.concrete,
          selectedFillColor: Palette.roseBud,
          activeColor: Palette.concrete,
          disabledColor: Palette.concrete,
          inactiveColor: Palette.concrete,
          selectedColor: Palette.roseBud,
        ),
        cursorColor: Palette.transparent,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `ClipRect` widgets unique keys:

> If the "new" child is the same widget type and key as the "old" child, but with different parameters, then AnimatedSwitcher will not do a transition between them, since as far as the framework is concerned, they are the same widget and the existing widget can be updated with the new parameters. To force the transition to occur, set a Key on each child widget that you wish to be considered unique (typically a ValueKey on the widget data that distinguishes this child from the others).

Comment: Thank you, but I already have keys `_mobileKey` and `_pinKey` and when I debug it goes through first statement and it just doesn't animate. then it goes to second statement and second widget animates properly